# Starting an Activity First in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, manifest

I'm having an issue starting activities in order, and I don't know if it is an issue in the manifest or in the code. I tested this code a while ago when it was working, but now it's not.
The first activity links to the second, which links to the third. I listed the first activity first in the manifest. However, when I start my emulator, it's the second activity that runs first. I am very confused. Here is my manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="hmdywifinal.com"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="Startpage">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity3"
        android:label="Activity3"></activity>
</application>
```

Do you think something is wrong with it?

Comment: Are you running your program from Activity1? Make sure you are not running it from Activity2

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot. Thank you. :D

Comment: Do you want to submit that as a question so I can give you points for it?

Comment: yes thank you. Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running your program from Activity1 and not from Activity2. 
If you run it from Activity2 it will skip Activity1 even though you have your manifest set like you described above.

Answer (score 0):

Order in which Manifest file declares Activities has nothing to do with the runtime order.
First Activity gets launched from a Launcher ( which is Activity1 in your case )

I am assuming you are launching Activity2 and 3 using Intents in your code. So you are in control on the way these activities get launched.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the api Demos, Which has got a similar application Proof Of Concept. It will give you a better idea on mving from one application to other.